# Azure AD: Unable to issue tokens from this api version

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am following [this guide](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) to create server that interacts Microsoft Graph API without any user presence to periodically fetch data. I have Global Administrator Directory role for my Azure Active Directory.  I have created an App using App registration portal as described. I am struck at step 3 of giving admin consent. I am getting the following error.

`http://localhost:8000/msft_callback?error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS50020%3a+We+are+unable+to+issue+tokens+from+this+api+version+for+a+Microsoft+account.+Please+contact+the+application+vendor+as+they+need+to+use+version+2.0+of+the+protocol+to+support+this.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+7303282e-06d1-4714-85a0-9db749b71800%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+8c031006-8193-4f32-9746-b0da8f9b975c%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2017-07-03+14%3a55%3a08Z&admin_consent=True&tenant={xxxxxxxxx}`

The error here says unable to to issue token from this version. But I am already on version 2. So I am not sure what is going wrong. And I don't see the consent experience screen at all. I select my account from which I want to give consent and then it redirects me to the redirect_uri I have provided in the registered App. Please help.

Comment: Which account you are using to register the app in  Microsoft App Registration Portal and what is your admin consent request .

Comment: It's the account that's linked to my Azure Directory. I think I have created personal account since it was not created through the azure portal. 

"what is your admin consent request". Can you rephrase this question? I don't understand.

Comment: We need the URI you're using for admin consent. This will tell us (among other things) which endpoint you're using and if that request is properly formed.

Comment: Are you using ADAL? Can you please share the `scope` & `response_type` from your request to Azure AD? It would probably help if you can share a fiddler trace while you simulate the error.

Comment: The guide says to redirect adminstrator to this address `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent` It is part of the 3rd step. I am correctly filling in the `client_id` and `redirect_uri` and setting `tenant` to common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a personal account with Global Administrator privilige. But it worked with work account created with *.onmicrosoft.com. It even worked with work account of a certified domain in the  Azure Portal.